# ajax won't make http post request

Tags: java, ajax, laravel

I'm on laravel 5.x and I want to call a controller with some parameter but it's doing nothing.

This is my action button :

```
<button class="button-details" data-idproject="{{ $project['id'] }}" data-fin="{{ $fin }}" data-debut="{{ $debut }}" data-iduser="{{$user['id']}}">+</button>
```

This is my ajax code:

````
         headers: {
             'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
         }
        });

        $(function() {
            $('table').tablesorter();
        });

        $(".button-details").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
                let user_id = $(this).data('iduser');
                let debut = $(this).data('debut');
                let fin = $(this).data('fin');
                let project_id = $(this).data('idproject');
            $.ajax( {
                url: '/details_project',
                type: 'POST',
                data: "user_id="+user_id,"project_id="+project_id,"debut="+debut,"fin="fin,
                success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    // $("."+id).hide();
                },
                error : function() {
                    console.log('ERROR');
                }
            });
        });```
````

Comment: "doing nothing" isn't particularly descriptive of the problem.  Is there an error on the browser's development console?  In the browser's debugging tools, is the AJAX request made?  If so, what is the server's response?  If it's not made, what happens when you use the browser's script debugger?  Is the click handler invoked at all?  If so, how does it fail?  If not, when you try to attach the click handler to the element does that jQuery selector find the element?  If not, why not?  Where is the element when that selector executes?

Comment: I doubt that it is doing nothing. Have you checked your console for any errors?

Comment: ` SyntaxError: missing : after property id ` and ` ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined[
    <anonyme> jQuery `

Comment: While I noticed that you're also missing a concatenation + here `"fin="fin,`, why not use this `data: {
user_id: user_id,
project_id: project_id,
debut: debut,
fin: fin
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing data as an object

```
    $(".button-details").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
            let user_id = $(this).data('iduser');
            let debut = $(this).data('debut');
            let fin = $(this).data('fin');
            let project_id = $(this).data('idproject');

            $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
        });

        $.ajax( {
            url: '/details_project',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                user_id: user_id,
                project_id: project_id,
                debut: debut,
                fin: fin
            },
            success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
            },
            error : function() {
                console.log('ERROR');
            }
        });
    });
```

In controller:

```
$post = $request->all();

//use data 
$user_id = $post['user_id'];
$project_id = $post['project_id'];
$debut = $post['debut'];
$fin = $post['fin'];
```